# UIWebView and SSO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an URL which I can log in with SSO with Safari, because I have saved a profile/certificate in the iPad simulator.

I have then created a `UIWebView`, which is loading this URL. But the problem is the SSO is not working anymore. So if I simulate this `UIWebView` app, then it stops at the login screen. Of course I have also saved the profile inside the simulator and if I enter the URL to the Safari from the simulator, the SSO is working.

Is anyone can help me with this issue? I need the SSO also works with the `UIWebView`.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to delete the app from the Ipad and put it again... maybe it will work

Comment: I delete this app from the simulator and re-started the simulation, it is still not working. So my question is, is creating a UIWebView with a URL so different from opening the URI in Safari, especially regarding the SSO stuff, e.g., where to look for the SSO certificate/profile?